# How to set an URL entered as string in Firestore as the image for UIImageView?

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore, uiimageview

I am very new to iOS development (with emphasis on very). I have a TableView I am attempting to populate with data from Firestore, but I can't figure out how to do it with the ImageView.

The Firestore collection I want to populate with is called "articles", where each doc represents an article I want to display in a cell. Each doc has this structure of data:

```
imageURL: https://someurl.com
title: 5 places you don't want to miss
```

I have created a UITableView with a UITableViewCell inside it in Storyboard, where the TableViewCell's ContentView contains an UIImageView for the 'imageURL' data in Firestore and a Label for the 'title' data in Firetore.

**The problem is that I don't how to turn the URL, which is entered as a string in the database, into an image that fills the UIImageView in the UITableViewCell.**

The fact that there will be a new string with url collected from the 'imageURL' field in the database for each snapshot just adds to the confusion on how to do this.

The UITableView in Storyboard is linked to ArtiklerTableViewController.swift.

Likewise is the UITableViewCell linked to ArtiklerCell.swift.

The two Swift files look like this now:

**ArtiklerTableViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ArtiklerTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var artiklerTableView: UITableView!

    var artiklerArray: [String] = []
    var documents: [DocumentSnapshot] = []

    var db: Firestore!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        configureTableView()
        loadData()




        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    }

    func configureTableView() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(ArtiklerCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ArtiklerCell")

        // remove separators for empty cells
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        // remove separators from cells
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none


    }


    func loadData() {
        db.collection("articles").getDocuments() { (QuerySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents : \(err)")
            }
            else {
                for document in QuerySnapshot!.documents {
                    let documentID = document.documentID
                    let artiklerImageView = document.get("imageURL") as! String
                    let artiklerTitleLabel = document.get("title") as! String
                    self.artiklerArray.append(artiklerTitleLabel)
                    print(artiklerImageView, artiklerTitleLabel, documentID)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("Tableview setup \(artiklerArray.count)")
        return artiklerArray.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ArtiklerCell", for: indexPath) as! ArtiklerCell
        let artikler = artiklerArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.artiklerTitleLabel.text = artikler

        print("Array is populated \(artiklerArray)")

        return cell
    }
}
```

**ArtiklerCell.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ArtiklerCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var artiklerImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var artiklerTitleLabel: UILabel!

    var db: Firestore!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        addSubview(artiklerImageView)
        addSubview(artiklerTitleLabel)
        configureImageView()

    }


    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    func configureImageView() {
        artiklerImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        artiklerImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    }   

}
```

Pardon my lack of knowledge! Can't seem to get it right no matter how many times I play around with different suggestions I find through Googling.

Any answer will be immensely appreciated!

Thanks in advance from a desperate girl who doesn't want to give up on learning iOS dev as I go while building an app.

Comment: Firestore is the database responsible for holding data. An image is considered a file that would not be stored in a database, but rather some sort of file storage. Firebase's file storage is called Storage. So you would have to get the location of the image (the filename is really enough) from the database and then go into Storage and get that image. The Storage will also return data, but this data you can convert into a `UIImage` in Swift using `UIImage(data:)`.

Comment: It seems you want to load an image into your UIImage based on a URL. Please see this article for a tutorial https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-load-a-remote-image-url-into-uiimageview.


Then update ```self.artiklerArray.append(artiklerTitleLabel)``` to ```self.artiklerArray.append((title: ..., imageUrl: ...)```. And then add and use a new method to your cell class, something like ```cell.loadArticle(artikler)```